# Can armored cable cross over a drain pipe?

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding

My electrical system uses the armored cable sheathing as a ground path.  I was placing some lines of AC in my walls, and I uncovered a drain pipe in the way.  At first, I covered the AC with electrical tape, then I decided to wedge a piece of plywood between the AC and the pipe.  At this point, I'm not concerned of any problems with contact between the two metal objects, but my question is: If I allowed the bare AC to cross the drain pipe, would that be hazardous?  I'm thinking that if there was a ground fault, and the AC sheathing was used to carry a current, the drain pipe would become energized and could shock someone taking a shower.  Am I right?

[image]
[image]

Comment: In most houses I have seen, the water pipes are bonded to the electrical grounding system anyway.